# Google OAuth2 login asks always for users access permissions

Tags: javascript, reactjs, electron, google-authentication

> **NOTE** I found a lot of similar questions on this topic but no one of them was helpful so I decided to ask a question with the code
> example.

I am using the Electron desktop app and users are authenticated via Google auth with their google accounts.

Problem is that on every logout users get asked for allowing access permissions for the app.

```
onLogin = async () => {
    if (!this.state.config || this.authWindow) return;
    try {
      const code = await this.openLoginWindow();
      const { data } = await this.getAccessToken(code);
      this.onGoogleLoginSuccess(data.id_token);
    } catch(err) {
      log.error(err);
      this.onGoogleLoginFailure();
    }
  }

openLoginWindow = () => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      const { isDev, ELECTRON_GOOGLE_ID } = this.state.config;

      const authWindow = this.authWindow = new electron.remote.BrowserWindow({
        width: 500,
        height: 600,
        show: true,
        parent: electron.remote.getCurrentWindow(),
        modal: true
      })

      if (!isDev) {
        authWindow.webContents.session.cookies.remove('https://accounts.google.com', 'SID', () => {});
      }

      const urlParams = {
        response_type: 'code',
        redirect_uri: GOOGLE_REDIRECT_URI,
        client_id: ELECTRON_GOOGLE_ID,
        scope: 'profile email',
      }

      authWindow.webContents.on('will-navigate', (event, url) => {
        this.onRedirect(url, authWindow, resolve, reject);
      });

      authWindow.webContents.on('did-get-redirect-request', (event, oldUrl, newUrl) => {
        this.onRedirect(newUrl, authWindow, resolve, reject);
      });

      authWindow.webContents.on('will-redirect', (event, url) => {
        this.onRedirect(url, authWindow, resolve, reject);
      });

      authWindow.on('close', () => this.authWindow = null);

      authWindow.loadURL(`${ GOOGLE_AUTHORIZATION_URL }?${ qs.stringify(urlParams) }`);
    });
  }

getAccessToken = code => {
    return axios.post(GOOGLE_TOKEN_URL, qs.stringify({
      code,
      client_id: this.state.config.ELECTRON_GOOGLE_ID,
      redirect_uri: GOOGLE_REDIRECT_URI,
      grant_type: 'authorization_code',
    }), {
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
      },
      withCredentials: false
    })
  }
```

Do you see something wrong in this code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
const urlParams = {
        response_type: 'code',
        redirect_uri: GOOGLE_REDIRECT_URI,
        client_id: ELECTRON_GOOGLE_ID,
        scope: 'profile email',
        providerParams: {
         access_type: 'offline',
         prompt: 'select_account'
         }
      }
```

Can you try once using this urlParams object ?

Comment: No, still is the same :/

Comment: I have the similar issue once upon a time. But changing the promt type from consent to  select_account worked for me. Not sure why it is not working in your case. Anyway I am not sure how it works in electron appications I have tested it in a web application